# What is the `< <()` syntax?

Tags: bash, shell

I've been using RVM for a while, and every time I just copied and pasted the following command to get it setup:

```
bash < <(curl -s https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/install/rvm)
```

It bugs me that I don't fully understand the syntax, and why we need the double <, and the parentheses.  Can some one explain this or point me to the right reference?

Comment: Is there any reason this isn't just: "curl -s ... | bash" ?  It looks like an example of excessive feature creep.

Comment: @William Pursell: I don't know of any difference in behavior between your version and this one.

Answer (score 13):

The first one is input redirection. It feeds the contents of a file into the program as input. The second construct is `<()` and it's process redirection: it treats output of a process like a file. In this case, the effect is that you will run the contents of that url as though it was a bash script -- very dangerous! If you don't trust to source completely, don't do that. An attacker could use this method to have you run commands that would compromise your system.

Comment: Good reply, especially when noting the security issue.

Comment: For insight into this feature, try this:  `echo <(id)`  It will give you an idea how the system is implemented and how it can be abused (e.g. `dd if=<(look foo)` `cp <(look foo) /tmp/x` etc)

Answer (score 2):

Just my 2 cents. Bashs structure `<()` as @Daenyth stated "treats output of a process like a file". This structure may be very useful. Just consider following:

```
 diff <(ls dir1) <(ls dir2)
```

This will use vimdiff to show differences between contents of *dir1* and *dir2*. Using `vimdiff` instead `diff` will even cooler.